# Why take first or last object from array of placemarks in reverse geocoding on iOS?

Tags: ios, geocoding, reverse

When working with reverse geocoding some address could be ambiguous for given location and the returned array of placemarks can contain multiple values (address gets multiple hits). This happens very rarely. Usually practice is to take first or last object from given array. So, I want to know why is this common practice. I've looked in Apple documentation and they also took object at index 0. Does the first object contains the most accurate address if the array of placemarks contains more than one object for given location (lat, long)? Thanks for your answers.